# flask argument in render_template

Tags: python, methods, flask

The name as an argument to hello function is assigned None, but why the name in render_template will take the value of the name if provided in the url? Basically my question is how Python knows which name is None and which name is given in the url?

```
 from flask import render_template
 @app.route('/hello')
 @app.route('/hello/<name>')
 def hello(name=None):
      return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```

the hello.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Hello from Flask</title>
{% if name %}
<h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: With your code, you'll always receive `name=None`. `<name>` in URL route and argument variable `name` in `hello()` function are the same.

Comment: Yes and that's why I am confused, because if I go to /hello I just see Hello World! but if I go to /hello/payam then I see Hello Payam, so how does render_template finds out the name is payam, if name=None?

Comment: the name=None is default, but if you provide it different argument, with going to /hello/<name>, it will take that instead.

Comment: You should read about how [Python's keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask is a framework and there is a lot of code behind the scenes (especially `werkzeug`) which does all the request processing, then it calls your view function and then it prepares a complete response.

So the answer is, that Python does not know the URL, but Flask does and calls your view function either with the `name` (overwriting the default `None`) or without it.

The `name` variable of the view function is passed to the template under the same name. Those are the two `name`s in this line:

```
return render_template('hello.html', name=name)
```