# Running a python script after a button is clicked

Tags: python, flask

So I have an html page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find the words</title>
    <h1>Find the Words</h1>
</head>
<body>
<p>Find the largest and the smallest word</p>
<textarea rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button">Find now!</button>
<br><br>
<label>Largest Word</label>
<input type='largest word'/>

<label>Smallest Word</label>
<input type='smallest word'/>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]
I want to run a python script which will find the largest and smallest word from a text and post the result back. The script(words.py) is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def find_small_large_words(given_string):
    new_list = given_string.split(" ")
    sorted_list = sorted(new_list, key=len)
    return 'Smallest: {0} & Largest: {1}'.format(sorted_list[0], sorted_list[-1])


words = "Ten years on from the financial crisis, it’s hard not to have a sense of déjà vu.Financial scandal and wrangles over financial rule-making still dominate " \
         "the headlines.The cyberhacking at Equifax compromisedpersonal records for half of the adult population of the United States.At SoFi, a one-time fintech darling"

print(find_small_large_words(words))
```

Ultimately, I want to run the python script on click of the "Find words" button and post them back in the two boxes. How can I do that here? I have read some suggestions about using django framework. Is there any other simple way? If so, how?

Edit: I am trying this in flask. My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import *
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():

    import words
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, I am unsure how to execute the python script specifically on the textarea input and post the output back.

Comment: Have you tried a onclick event with your button?

Comment: If you have a *web* server, you could google for `cgi`. Other than that, read the tutorial of your favourite web frame work.

Comment: @Tomm I thought onclick event only executes scripts written in php or js. I will take a look.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Is this task possible with Flask?

Comment: It should be possible with Flash, i would suggest Flask over jquery aswell

Comment: Yes, there are a gazillion ways to do this. Flask, Django, CGI, Web.py, Tornado, http.server, Asphalt, Pyramid, *WSGI, whatever. You just need to make the choice yourself. Can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need a form to send it's content

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ///
});

$("#submit").onclick(function"() {
  $.post( "url_for('main.calculate')", function( data ) {
     $("#smallest_word").val(data.smallest);
     $("#longest_word").val(data.longest);
  });

});
```

```html
<form action="" method="">
  <textarea name="txt_words"></textarea>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<input type="text" id="smallest_word" />
<input type="text" id="longest_word" />
```

you have two options on how to do it, they are the same but still they have their differences.

1- you can use jquery.
for this, you should write a jquery post method so you can post the form containing the text box. [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

then, you should get the content and again using jquery populate your inputs values. [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

then, you need the view in your flask app:

```
@mod.route('calculate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def calculate():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      text = request.form.get('text_words', 'None')
      if text:
         # do calculate!
         data = {"smallest": calculated_smallest, "longest": calculated_longest}
         return jsonify(data)
   else:
       # it's a GET render the template
       return render_template('form.html')
```

2- you could send the form, and then return the variables for largest and smallest with render_template so you get those variables and can handle in jinija2 template that if smallest and largest are available, show their content in the input boxes. [send variable to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971263/flask-argument-in-render-template)

this is flask code and i have written in on the fl

Comment: I just started to learn flask. My flask app code so far is this: `#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import *
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    import words
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()`

However, I am not sure how to run the python function specifically on the input given in the textarea.

Comment: you should paste this code in your question, it'll be more easy to read and better place for it,  i'll update my answer for you, but i just give you snippet so you can try and learn!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your objective here, I suggest you to write a javascript/jquery script, instead of python which necessitates server handling (unnecessary, since you only want it to be posted back to the html without saving it in database or do any I/O).

If you really want to run this in python though, you may need framework like flask or django as you mentioned. If you do, try to save the user input into a string variable before executing the python script. For example:

```
the_string_var = request(your_form_data)
```

but again, you may need to create form first or using AJAX/jQuery so you could send the data to your server.