# Do optional routing parameters in flask need to be set to "none" in a function?

Tags: python, flask, url-routing

This code is taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_optional-activities to setup a basic webapp using flask and python in visual studio code.

Why does the function "hello_there" have the parameter "name = None"? Shouldn't the function just pass in the name without specifying anything else? To me, the render_template should be setting name to None, since "name = None" is the function parameter. This answer: [flask argument in render_template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971263/flask-argument-in-render-template) hints that flask overwrites the function parameter. If that's the case, is there a need for the function to have the "name = None" parameter?

```
@app.route("/hello/")
@app.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello_there(name = None):
    return render_template(
        "hello_there.html",
        name=name,
        date=datetime.now()
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name = None` is what is called a [default argument value](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) and in the case of the function you posted seems to serve as a way to ensure the function `hello_there` works with or without a `name` being passed.

Notice the function decorators:

```py
@app.route("/hello/")
@app.route("/hello/<name>")
```

This means that the expected call for this function is either *with* or *without* the parameter name. By setting `name` default argument to `None`, we can ensure that if `name` is never passed the function is still properly able to rendered the page. Notice the following:

```
>>> def func(a):
...     return a

>>> print(func())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

versus

```py
>>> def func(a = None):
...     return a

>>> print(func())
None
```

Notice how on the function you posted `name` is referenced in the `return`:

```py
    return render_template(
        "hello_there.html",
        name=name,
        date=datetime.now()
    )
```

If `name` is not defined beforehand, then you would see the error listed above. Another thing is -- if I had to guess -- I would assume that within the template `hello_there.html` there is a context switching for when `name` is `None` and for when it is something:

```html
{% if name %}
    <b> Hello {{ name }}! </b>
{% else %}
    <b> Hello! </b>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So basically the parameter in the function defintion, "a = None" is basically saying, "if no parameter is provided when this function is called, return None instead of throwing an error"?

Comment: Yes, in part to that specific example. A more generalized statement would be: A _parameter definition_ inside the function's _input arguments list_, `def func(a=None)`, is basically saying: "if no parameter `a` is provided when this function is called, pass `None` for `a`.